# Adding text in a Plotly bar chart in R shrinks the bar area

Tags: r, plotly, bar-chart

When I add text in a Plotly bar chart, it slightly shrinks the bar area.

```
# Shrunken plot area
require(plotly)

cats = c(letters, paste0(letters,'2'), paste0(letters,'3'), paste0(letters,'4') )

data = data.frame(
  y_axis_cat = rep(cats,8),
  x_axis_num = rep(5,length(cats)*8),
  cat = rep(paste0('Cat ',1:8), length(cats))
)

plotly::plot_ly(data) %>%
  plotly::add_bars(
    x = ~x_axis_num,
    y = ~y_axis_cat,
    color=~cat
  ) %>%
  plotly::add_text(
    x = 40,
    y = ~y_axis_cat,
    text = '40'
  )
```

[image: Plot narrowed on y-axis]

Removing the text displays the plot across the whole y-axis

```
# Full plot area
plotly::plot_ly(data) %>%
  plotly::add_bars(
    x = ~x_axis_num,
    y = ~y_axis_cat,
    color=~cat
  )
```

[image: Plot across full y-axis]

Is it possible to control how much area is taken up by the plots on each axis?

Note that using `add_trace()` instead of `add_text()` produces the same result:

```
...
 %>%
  plotly::add_trace(
    x = 40,
    y = ~y_axis_cat,
    mode='text',
    type='scatter',
    text = '40'
  )
```

Comment: Do you want the text to the right of the bar area then?

Comment: What is your expected outcome?

Comment: @Quinten the first plot had a line at the top and bottom with no bars to the right of them. Also notice the distance from the bottom bar, "a", to the x-axis "0". I would like the bars to extend as they do in the second plot, but with the text.